# WKWebView takeSnapshot returns a blank image on very specific sites

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm using takeSnapshot on a WKWebView that loads a specified site in the background, in addition to some evaluateJavaScript lines that get the correct height. The code works great until a user requests a very specific type of website (with a distinguishing factor I'm not sure of), and the image it returns will be completely blank, with an alpha of 0. The JavaScript code to get the dimensions still work correctly, however.

I can't seem to identify the issue here. Sites like walmart.com, example.com, and theage.com.au work correctly, but very specific URLs fail, such as:

- https://www.wikihow.com/Cancel-Auto-Shutdown-in-Windows-10 (but not the WikiHow homepage).
- https://www.thewindowsclub.com/abort-system-shutdown-windows

Is there a factor anyone can think of that could cause this? Perhaps I need to inject some JavaScript that tells the site that it's in the foreground (because the WKWebView is loaded in AppDelegate)?

In addition, apple.com was working great until they added that video for the new Apple TV+ show, because it seems to scale to the height of your screen. Are there any solutions here?

Perhaps there's a better solution to capture a WKWebView's content as an image than takeSnapshot, as it seems to have several strange edge cases where it fails. Does anyone know of alternatives?

Below is the code I'm using to take a snapshot:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollWidth") { (width, error) in
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width as! CGFloat, height: height as! CGFloat)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
                            let snapshotConfiguration = WKSnapshotConfiguration()
                            snapshotConfiguration.afterScreenUpdates = false

                            webView.takeSnapshot(with: snapshotConfiguration) { (image, error) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    print(error)
                                } else {
                                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("imageReady"), object: nil, userInfo: ["image": image] as! [String: Any])
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
    
}
```

Comment: This seems suspect to me, why are you capturing the users web session from Walmart and apple?

Comment: @valosip The web view loads strictly in the background, and serves the image to the user once loaded. This program is designed for a certain edge case where presenting the user with the site on an actual WKWebView is not possible.